# Zend Db Results escaped and html url encoded

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-db

When I use Zend DB (PDO Mysql Adapter), I'm getting back results that are not only escaped, but also HTML url-encoded.

I'm inserting the rows into the database as is, not escaped or html encoded. I'm curious to know:

- How I can get back results that aren't escaped and html encoded,
- If I should be doing something to treat the data before inserts,
- And if it isn't possible to get back results that aren't escaped and html url encoded, how to do it myself.

I'd like to know if retrieving the results as escaped and html encoded is actually the proper way to do things?

Comment: Actually I think you just wonder why the strings are encoded. I would ask more straight forward and provide some code what you actually do otherwise your question is only an invitation to guess around. AFAIK ZF does not does how you describe is does. So the "error" must be somewhere in your data-processing.

Comment: Ahh. You are correct. Its not due to Zend Db. My mistake. Please use that as an answer so I can approve it.

Comment: Done, added that as an answer. Please check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I think you just wonder why the strings are encoded.

AFAIK ZF does not does how you describe is does. So the "error" must be somewhere in your data-processing.

> *Additional Note:* To improve your questions in the future, I would ask more straight forward and provide some code what you actually do otherwise your question is much of an invitation to guess around. With a concrete example it often works best.